# How to remove text from order summary in Prestashop

Tags: html, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

[image]

As shown in screenshot there are 4 lines in the order summary but we want to remove 3rd line from this summary. 
However i know we can change the text from translations but don't know how to remove.

Comment: You can use CSS pseudo-class :nth-child(3) to hide based on the DOM structure. Ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit the right file for the payment method, in your case is the bankwire module.

If you have the default template go to `prestashop/themes/default-bootstrap/modules/bankwire/views/templates/front/` and edit this file
`payment_execution.tpl`.

This file is in smarty code, specifically you have to remove this line code:

```
- {l s='Bank wire account information will be displayed on the next page.' mod='bankwire'}
```

Comment: hello can you tell me what tpl file we can edit for bank wire confirmation page?

Comment: `payment_return.tpl` in `hook` folder instead of `front`, of course :)